# How to auto update one worksheet from another?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I update one worksheet from another?

Let's say I have Sheet1 and Sheet2. Whatever cell I type in Sheet 1 automatically updates that specific cell in Sheet2.

Comment: Write macro and put its code in method that is called on change event (e.g. `Worksheet_Change`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet that you write, in VBA,

[image]

create `Worksheet_Change` event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    Worksheets(2).Range(Target.Address) = Target        
End Sub
```

Anything you write on the first worksheet would be present on the second one.

Comment: @blazing - so, instead of trying it for a second, decided to take a screenshot, upload it and write a comment about it?

Comment: I did try it, it works thanks very much. Just wanted to make sure I followed your instructions correctly.

Comment: Is there anyway to modify that code so that if i type in any cell in sheet 1, I can choose which cell in sheet 2 to update?

Comment: @blazing - probably with an `InputBox()`

Comment: So something like WorkSheets(2).Range(Target(InputBox())? Sorry as I said completely new to excel. @Vityata

Comment: More like `Worksheets(2).Range(InputBox("")) = Target`, @blazing

Comment: @blazing - did you try to write "A1" in the input box?

Comment: That worked thanks and one more thing. Lets say I wanted to take the value of what I type in from sheet 2 and always place into one specific column going downwards, how would I do it. Eg http://prntscr.com/j48ei3 (from sheet 2) to always update this column in sheet 1 http://prntscr.com/j48ewi. @Vityata

Comment: @blazing - it is a good idea to ask these in a separate question.